# How to splice /dev/mem?

Tags: c, linux, splice

I have an external FPGA device that is dumping vast amounts of data via PCIe to a reserved (using boot-loader parameters) contiguous memory region.  This memory region will always start in the same location.

I now want to dump that data over UDP as quickly as possible.  I don't care about examining this data so there is no need to bring it into user-space.  As such, my research has indicated using zero-copy is the fastest/best way to do this.

I am trying to `int memFd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY);`, then using `memFd` in `sendfile` and `splice` function calls, but these are failing.

It took a few days, but I finally saw in the `sendfile` source that the input file descriptor must be a regular file (a detail frustratingly left out of the man page as far as I can tell), and `/dev/mem` is not a regular file.  Anyway, I looked around some more, and now am confident `splice` is the call I want to use.

However, this is failing as well with an errno of 14-EFAULT which means "bad address" (again frustratingly, this error code is not mentioned in the `splice` man page).  I've looked over the source code for `splice`, and can see a few times where EFAULT is returned, but I just don't see how the arguments I'm passing are causing a problem.

My simplified, non-error checking code is below;

```
 int filedes[2];
 int memFd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY);
 int fileFd = open("myTestFile.txt", O_RDONLY);
 loff_t offset = START_OF_MEM_REGION;
 int sockFd = ConfigureMySocket();

 pipe(filedes);  // this returns 0, so the pipes are good

 int ret = splice(memFd, &offset, filedes[1], NULL, 128, SPLICE_F_MOVE); // this fails with EFAULT
 //int ret = splice(memFd, NULL, filedes[1], NULL, 128, 0); // this also fails with EFAULT
 //int ret = splice(fileFd, NULL, filedes[1], NULL, 128, 0); // this works just fine

 // this is never reached because the splice call above hangs. If I run the
 // fileFd splice call instead this works just fine
 ret = splice(filedes[0], NULL, sockFd, NULL, 128, 0);
```

My system info:

- embedded device running linux 3.1.10 on ARM architecture
- running as root user
- kernel was NOT compiled with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`

Other fun facts:

- I have a 2.6 linux CentOS virtual machine and this code works fine up to offsets of ~1MB.  However, this kernel was compiled with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`, so I attribute the 1MB limit to that.
- I can `mmap` to the memory region just fine and see the data the FPGA is writing.

My questions are:

1. Is using `splice` the right way to do this?  Does someone think there's a better way?
2. If `splice` is right, anybody have any idea what could be happening here?  Could there be a kernel compiler flag preventing this from working?  I was reading source code from `splice.c`, but it wasn't the 3.1.10 version, so perhaps something has changed?  Either way, it's a bummer to see this work just fine in the VM but not in the embedded environment.

EDIT: I have downloaded the 3.1.10 source from kernal.org and unfortunately see no major differences from what I was looking at on free-electrons.com with a different version.  Looks like to me all the splice code is in /fs/splice.c.  `do_splice(...)` must be the code that gets executed.  My first call to `splice` (using `memFd` and `filedes[1]`) should be dropping down to `if (opipe) {`... here you can see that `EFAULT` is returned if `copy_from_user` or `copy_to_user` fail .. how could these be failing?  There can't be anything wrong with my `&offset` variable since I get the same error if this is `NULL` or no error if I substitute `fileFd` in place of `memFd`.  Also something of interest,, there are no errors if I replace 128 with 0 (number of bytes to write).  The places where `EFAULT` is returned, I just don't see how the file descriptor even factors into that logic,, unless `EFAULT` is getting returned by some deeper function calls...

These are the snippets from `splice.c`

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE6(splice, int, fd_in, loff_t __user *, off_in,
        int, fd_out, loff_t __user *, off_out,
        size_t, len, unsigned int, flags)
{
    long error;
    struct file *in, *out;
    int fput_in, fput_out;

    if (unlikely(!len))
        return 0;

    error = -EBADF;
    in = fget_light(fd_in, &fput_in);
    if (in) {
        if (in->f_mode & FMODE_READ) {
            out = fget_light(fd_out, &fput_out);
            if (out) {
                if (out->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE)
                    error = do_splice(in, off_in,
                              out, off_out,
                              len, flags);
                fput_light(out, fput_out);
            }
        }

        fput_light(in, fput_in);
    }

    return error;
}

static long do_splice(struct file *in, loff_t __user *off_in,
              struct file *out, loff_t __user *off_out,
              size_t len, unsigned int flags)
{
    struct pipe_inode_info *ipipe;
    struct pipe_inode_info *opipe;
    loff_t offset, *off;
    long ret;

    ipipe = get_pipe_info(in);
    opipe = get_pipe_info(out);

    if (ipipe && opipe) {
        if (off_in || off_out)
            return -ESPIPE;

        if (!(in->f_mode & FMODE_READ))
            return -EBADF;

        if (!(out->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE))
            return -EBADF;

        /* Splicing to self would be fun, but... */
        if (ipipe == opipe)
            return -EINVAL;

        return splice_pipe_to_pipe(ipipe, opipe, len, flags);
    }

    if (ipipe) {
        if (off_in)
            return -ESPIPE;
        if (off_out) {
            if (!(out->f_mode & FMODE_PWRITE))
                return -EINVAL;
            if (copy_from_user(&offset, off_out, sizeof(loff_t)))
                return -EFAULT;
            off = &offset;
        } else
            off = &out->f_pos;

        ret = do_splice_from(ipipe, out, off, len, flags);

        if (off_out && copy_to_user(off_out, off, sizeof(loff_t)))
            ret = -EFAULT;

        return ret;
    }

    if (opipe) {
        if (off_out)
            return -ESPIPE;
        if (off_in) {
            if (!(in->f_mode & FMODE_PREAD))
                return -EINVAL;
            if (copy_from_user(&offset, off_in, sizeof(loff_t)))
                return -EFAULT;
            off = &offset;
        } else
            off = &in->f_pos;

        ret = do_splice_to(in, off, opipe, len, flags);

        if (off_in && copy_to_user(off_in, off, sizeof(loff_t)))
            ret = -EFAULT;

        return ret;
    }

    return -EINVAL;
}
```

Comment: Why not DMA direct to the NIC? That's probably doable on your ARM. You'd have to have (in effect) a device driver for the NIC implemented in the FPGA, not so bad if you're doing UDP. And it'd only be any good if the UDP is faster than your FPGA's data rate... Going via CPU memory like you're doing is going to add time.

Comment: @bazza That is a good idea, however the guy writing the firmware for the fpga has no desire to setup a DMA controller. We are also trying to stay out of kernel-driver space just to save on complexity. If we get to the end and it's simply too slow and we still have time/money, this will be a good idea to consider. We expect the FPGA to be fastest and everything else slower, so data will get dropped somewhere.

Comment: Depending on your exact system architecture there wouldn't necessarily have to be a kernel driver. It would simply be something the FPGA does to the NIC outside the control of the CPU. Dropping data nicely could be tricky though. Setting that aside, I guess you need to trade the time taken to do it all in the FPGA vs the time taken to bend Linux to your needs. You could take a look at kernel bypass, which would at least allow you to do the packet building yourself rather than trying to pass the data down through the kernels own network stack.

Comment: there is so much I don't know :( Yes, all of that sounds much better/faster/stronger. There's a lot of variables to this project, and I think right now we're all in "proof-of-concept" mode, so as much as an emphasis I put on speed, really familiarity probably trumps all that right now. Once we get something going, and if it turns out to be too slow, I will revisit this. Figuring out a thing or two about DMA would be a good start. Thanks a lot for the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

`mmap` the memory region, then use a regular `write` or `vmsplice`

Comment: Thanks, using a regular `write` does work, and the way this is going I will settle for that, but based on what I've read `splice` should be faster (speed is going to be very important) so ideally I'd like to get this working. Also at this point I'm damn curious what the problem is.

Comment: I suggest you profile it and compare which of the two (vmsplice or write) fares better (vmsplice is the counterpart to splice which does operate with memory pages on one end instead of a pipe).

Comment: This is its own question, but if I reserve memory with `memmap`, what space is that in? I wouldn't call that user or kernel space. System space? As far as I can tell Linux doesn't know about it (no mention in `dmesg`), other than the fact Linux won't claim it as evident in `/proc/iomem`. Really I'm quite surprised I can `mmap` to it. What I'm getting at is, from what I've read about `vmsplice`, it sounds like its purpose is to move user space memory to kernel space. If that makes the requirement to move this data from system space -> user space -> kernel space, `mmap, write` seems best.

Comment: @yano: You're overthinking this. From the perspective of pointer access distinction "kernel space" vs "user space" boils down to page access and protection flags, and the position in virtual address space. `mmap` (there's no 'me' at the beginning) does not reserve memory, but creates an association between user virtual address space (memory) and "something" else, where "something" may just be contiguous physical memory. What `vmsplice` does care about is, that the pointer that's passed to it addresses virtual address space that has a user space mapping.

Comment: @yano: When it comes to mmap-ed space, you should look at `/proc/$PID/maps`; iomem is something entirely different, peripheral address space, i.e. IO to these addresses will make peripherals do something. And not, vmsplice does not "move" things between address spaces. Yes, vmsplice has the notion of "gifting" pages to the kernel, but that does only mean that you give the kernel full control over the pages and promise not to mess with them until the kernel is done using them.

Comment: Right, I mean I'm using `memmap` as a boot load parameter to reserve system memory before linux ever gets started; something like `memmap=40M$1024M` which reserves 40MB starting at physical address 0x40000000 (I can see in `/proc/iomem` linux has excluded 40MB from 0x40000000-0x427fffff from its System Ram). Then in my code I use `mmap` to obtain a virtual address pointer to that region. Thanks for the `vmsplice` explanation,, yeah if both `write` and `vmsplice` work with the `mmap` pointer I should figure out which one is faster.